# How serialize time zone part of ZonedDateTime with jackson correctly - offset is handled correctly

Tags: jackson, zoneddatetime

My Jackson is configured with

disabled `DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` (jsr310 is also in place)

Thus de/serializing ZonedDateTime is at least correctly preserving the offset part. But the serialization of a ZonedDateTime is removing the zone. Is there a configuration to preserve the zone info?
Or in other words how to get this test green?:

```
@Test
public void zonedDateTime() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ZonedDateTime time = random.nextObject(ZonedDateTime.class);
    String string = om.writeValueAsString(time);
    ZonedDateTime timeReadBack = om.readValue(string, ZonedDateTime.class);
    assertThat(timeReadBack, is(time));
}
```

If not possible only with configuration is there code for correct de/serilization?